# react table: refresh table after new data received

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to refresh my react table after new data is received. I was expecting I trigger this when I change state, however it doesnt work.

Below is state and the update function:

```
this.state = {
    switchListSelected: [],
    switchListData: [],
    interfaceStatusData: [],
    interfaceErrorsData: []
}

updateParentState(data, element){       
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return prevState[element].push(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `setState` wrong. You should call `setState` with the new state (or an updater function which returns the new state) and optionally a callback which will be called when the update is done. You can check the usage of `setState` in the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

In your example the updateParentState function should look like this:

```
updateParentState = (data, element) => {       
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [element]: [...this.state[element], data]
    })
}
```

Note that the state of a component should never be mutated directly. Hence the creation of a new array with the spread operator instead of [Array.push which mutates the array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Answer (score 0):

**2 issues here :**

- When using `setState` you need to return an object of the state's attributes to update, here you return the result of `prevState[element].push(data)` (the array length).
- You are mutating the array by using `Array.push()`, you need to use immutable pattern updates to correctly trigger a render with your updated state.

This should work for your case :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  [element]: [...prevState[element], data],
}));
```